# App shows leak in Instrument, What's wrong with this simple code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, instruments

I am simple exporting my data into CSV file. But when I click on Export Button, Leak Instrument shows `[NSPlaceholderMutableString init]` error.

I have not used `Placeholder` anywhere in my `NSMutableString`, then What's so wrong that Instrument shows Leak.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)btnExportDataPressed:(id)sender
{
    csvString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    csvString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"No.,Name,Type,MaskPAN,SwipeTime\n"];
    NSString *msg = @"";

    if (self.totalCards.count>0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<self.totalCards.count; i++)
        {
            self.cardInfo = [self.totalCards objectAtIndex:i];
            [csvString appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%@ %@,%@,%@,%@\n",i+1,self.cardInfo.firstName,self.cardInfo.lastName,self.cardInfo.type,self.cardInfo.maskedPAN,self.cardInfo.swipeTime]];
        }
        NSLog(@"csvString:%@",csvString);

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ORANGE_BOWL_%@",[NSDate date]];

        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv",fileName]];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
        msg = @"Data exported successfully. Connect the device to iTunes to get the records.";
    }
    else
    {
        msg = @"No Data to Export";
    }

    [csvString release];        
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Discover Orange Bowl," message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Below is error pic from Instrument

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but just so you know, the `Placeholder` comes from the way that the `NSMutableString` class works. This class is actually a class cluster that instantiates a concrete subclass of itself when initialized. In other words, `NSMutableString` itself isn't a class, but will provide you with a particular subclass suited to your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a memory leak right at the top of your code:

```
csvString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
csvString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"No.,Name,Type,MaskPAN,SwipeTime\n"];
```

So you're allocating memory for a mutable string (line 1) which inceases the retain count by 1, and then in line 2 you lose your pointer reference to that because you assign another string to the pointer. This will leak memory for sure; not sure if the rest of your code is doing anything else bad.

So delete the first line -- it's useless and only serves to cause a memory leak.

Also, your `[csvString release]` line looks wrong because when you last assigned something to `csvstring` you used `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat]` which doesn't increase the retain count (and hence you shouldn't decrease it by using `release`). So try removing the line that says `[csvString release];`.

The Leaks tool can show slightly baffling references to object you didn't actually use; this is caused by these objects being used internally by objects that you did use (and leak).

Comment: then how can I do this thing. I also tried using simple NSMutableString without alloc/init. But same problem arises... Can you suggest me some way out...

Comment: I believe you also need to delete the `release` on `csvString` at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`csvString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"No.,Name,Type,MaskPAN,SwipeTime\n"];`

To

`[csvString appendFormat:@"No.,Name,Type,MaskPAN,SwipeTime\n"];`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `alloc`, `init`, and `release` on `csvString` if you are initializing it with `stringWithFormat:`

The `init` and `stringWithFormat:` methods are documented in the NSString documentation under [Creating and Initializing Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString).  You should choose one or the other, not both.  In this case, you probably just want to go with `stringWithFormat:`.

You should read up on [Objective-C memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) but the general guideline here is:  If the method you are using to create the object starts with `init`, then you use `alloc` and `release`.  If the method does not start with `init`, then you do not not use `alloc` and `release`.

Comment: I tried simply using NSMutableString without alloc/init... but same leaks are their in Instrument. So i tried with alloc/init. Can you suggest me some way out...

Comment: Did you remove the `release` as well?